# Jupyter notebook not loading through anaconda promot or cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-console

installed the latest anaconda, and this is the error. please help. I have added anaconda to the path.

```
(base) C:\Users\Sagar Singh>jupyter notebook
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\Sagar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\Sagar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Sagar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Sagar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\Sagar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\Sagar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Sagar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)

(base) C:\Users\Sagar Singh>conda -V
conda 4.8.3
```

Comment: Have you checked: [this issue on github which seems to be the same](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3435).

Answer (score 0):

There are some conflict in your conda. Try fixing it with this way.

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```